# SFMC MobileConnect not sending SMS when using AMPScript/dynamic variables

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

Here's my SMS message:

```
%%[
set @accountUserName = AttributeValue('Account_User_Name__c')
set @QRCodeLink = AttributeValue('QR_Code_Link__c')
set @eventName = AttributeValue('Event_Name__c')
set @locationAddress = AttributeValue('GCVMS_Street_Address_1__c')
set @appointmentDate = AttributeValue('AppointmentDate__c')
set @appointmentStartTime = AttributeValue('Appointment_Slot_Start_Time__c')
set @appointmentEndTime = AttributeValue('Appointment_Slot_End_Time__c')
set @accountUserName = AttributeValue('Account_User_Name__c')
set @QR_Code = AttributeValue('QR_Code__c')
set @VaccineManu = AttributeValue('Manufacturer__c')
]%%

Hello Username: %%=v(@accountUserName)=%%

Thank you for using the Texas Public Health Vaccine Scheduler (TPHVS), an online COVID-19 vaccine scheduling system. Please find your appointment details below.

Event Location:%%=v(@eventName)=%%

Address:%%=v(@locationAddress)=%%

Appointment Date:%%=Format(@appointmentDate, "MMMM d, yyyy")=%%

Appointment Time:%%=Format(@AppointmentStartTime, "h:mm tt")=%% - %%=Format(@AppointmentEndTime, "h:mm tt")=%%

Vaccine Manufacturer:%%=v(@VaccineManu)=%%

To reschedule your appointment or find out about transportation support, please call 1-833-832-7067.

Use this QR code (%%=v(@QRCodeLink=%%)) to check-in to your appointment when you arrive.

You may cancel your appointment by clicking the following link: https://sforce.co/3xbf2rq or by calling 1-833-832-7067.

Thank you for helping keep Texans healthy and safe!
```

Whenever I go to send it via Automation Studio, I never receive the SMS.

If I change the content to something like:

```
This is a test
```

It sends just fine.  I'm just wondering what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: those attributes all exist on mobileconnect demographics?

Comment: I found the problem.  AMPScript error on the "QRCodeLink" towards the bottom.  Doh.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend pasting this whole code into a blank Email in Email Studio Content.
Then do a preview and test and select the contact audience DE for the AttribueValue functions to leverage.

You will see there is an error in the syntax or any other possible AMPscript issues. That will help you with your trouble shooting.